# pairs of prime numbers, $x$ and $y$, where $x=(y \times c)+1$

Tags: prime-numbers

I need to find pairs of primes that fit the equation that
$x=(y \times c)+1$, where $c$ is a positif integer. or you can say that $x\equiv 1\pmod y$

is there a criterion in finding these prime pairs, or is it just coincidences.
if so then what are the examples.

Comment: Take any prime $x$ and let $y$ be any prime factor of $x-1$.  $x$ has to be at least $3$ to ensure that $x-1$ has a prime factor.

Comment: do you mean that $c$ is fixed? Or you just want $x\equiv 1\pmod y$?

Comment: $c$ is not fixed, yes i mean $x\equiv 1\pmod y$. thank you for that insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment above, if you first fix the larger prime $x$, it is easy to compute the possible values for $y$, so long as you can compute a prime factorization.

On the other hand, if you start with the smaller prime $y$ and try to search for $x$, it is a theorem that there are infinitely many primes in the list $1, 1+y, 1+2y, 1+3y,\ldots$ which are possible choices of $x$. (Namely, this is a special case of Dirchlet's Theorem on arithmetic progressions.) So in that sense the criterion is that it is always possible to find such a pair.

I'm not sure what else you would want for a criterion. Maybe you want to know how long it takes to find the first prime - this is probably a bit up to "coincidences" as you say, but there are approximations available, generalizing the prime number theorem. You can read about the [prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions) or the [Siegel-Walfisz theorem (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%E2%80%93Walfisz_theorem).